# PostgreSQL: Declare a cursor for prepared statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, cursor, prepared-statement

The following `DECLARE` fails:

```
PREPARE stmt(bigint) AS SELECT ...;
DECLARE crs CURSOR FOR stmt;
```

According to https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-declare.html, 
`stmt` has to be either `SELECT` or `VALUES` command.

I use `PREPARE` statement in a latency-critical section of the code in which thousands of quick queries are emitted. Parsing and generating a query plan each time would be performance killer. However, in some rare cases the query can return millions of records and the result doesn't fit into memory.

Is there a way to declare a cursor for prepared statement in PostgreSQL? If not, are there any workarounds?

Comment: prepared stmt is for "Any SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or VALUES statement." and cant be used with cursors. your question is if you can somehow `FETCH` from prepared select?..

Comment: That's right. I want to combine the high latency of prepared statements with the ability to fetch results part by part.

Comment: I think it's impossible. but let lions and bears say their word. It would look like `declare l CURSOR FOR execute`... or `prepare a as declare` both make no sense to me

Comment: One way I can think of is to add LIMIT clause to the prepared statement, and check if the limit has been reached. If so, declare a cursor for the same query but now without the LIMIT clause. Is there any other way?

Comment: please update post with code. I dont understand your idea

Comment: Vao Tsun: Not sure, how I should update the post. The code is already there:
```
PREPARE stmt(bigint) AS SELECT ...;
DECLARE crs CURSOR FOR stmt;
```
I think the exact SELECT query is not important here.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ecpg-commands.html#ECPG-EXECUTING

This can be done through ECPG C library in c code. 
One can create prepared statement in C code as:

```
EXEC SQL PREPARE stmt1 FROM "SELECT oid,datname FROM pg_database WHERE oid > ?";
```

and then create cursor for that statement as:

```
EXEC SQL DECLARE foo_bar CURSOR FOR stmt1;
```

fetch result form cursor within infinite loop.

```
EXEC SQL OPEN foo_bar USING 100;


while(1){
    EXEC SQL FETCH NEXT FROM foo_bar INTO :dboid, :dbname;
}
```

This is available with 9.1 version of postgresql.